# What is the difference between `add`and `setup` in jQuery special events?

Tags: jquery

I am learning how to create custom events with jQuery, but I'm a little bit confused with some hooks.

What is exactly the difference between `setup` and `add` (and between `teardown` and `remove`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setup` hook is called the first time an event by that name is attached on an element, so you'd want to do any work that applied whenever that event might be active for example. The `add` hook is called every time an event is attached and happens after `setup` if it happens to be the first time the event is attached on the element. So the pairings are `setup/teardown` and `add/remove`.

It's not very common to need to use the special events hooks. Be aware that if you change the behavior of standard DOM names like `click` or `mouseover`, chaos will surely follow.  jQuery itself uses the special events system for several standard DOM names, and setting your own will clobber those.